# Android built-in styles

Tags: android, styles

I'm a learner of Android programming and I'm currently reading this book, well it's the first,  `HeadFirst Android Development`.
In chapter 14 `Navigation Drawers`, there was this attribute of `TextView` `textAppearance` that was given a value of `@style/textAppearance.AppCompat.Body1`.
The book said it was a built-in styles that makes text look slightly bolder.
My question is, how many built-in `styles` does Android has?
I want to know all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the following link you will get all the styling options for `TextView`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView

you can check the styling options for other views from the left panel of the same link by clicking on other classes.

Answer (score 0):

A **style** is defined in an XML resource that is separate from the XML that specifies the layout. This XML file resides under **res/values/** directory of your project and will have  as the root node which is mandatory for the style file.

You can define multiple styles per file using  tag but each style will have its name that uniquely identifies the style. Android style attributes are set using  tag as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
     <style name="CustomFontStyle">
     <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
     <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
     <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
     <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">12pt</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>/> 
     </style>
 </resources>
```

**Using Styles**

Once your style is defined, you can use it in your XML Layout file using style attribute as follows

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_id"
  style="@style/CustomFontStyle"
  android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

**Always**, when you are writing in XML to find the built-in attribute use:

```
attribute_name="@android:attribute_value
```

The **@android:** will list all the built-in the attribute for a given attribute you want, for Example:
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"

**Default Styles & Themes**

Android provides a large collection of **styles** and **themes** that you can use in your applications. You can find a reference of all available styles in the **R.style** class. To use the styles listed here, replace all underscores in the style name with a period. For example, you can apply the Theme_NoTitleBar theme with "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar".
You can see the following source code for Android styles and themes- [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)